# How to convert my dataframe to a complete int dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, binary-tree

I need to run Binary Tree Classifier on a dataset given to me.

This is what I've done.

```
data = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
print(data.head())
x = data.drop(' brand', axis = 1)
y = data[' brand']
```

```
    mpg   cylinders  cubicinches   hp  weightlbs   time-to-60   year     brand
0  14.0           8          350  165       4209           12   1972       US.
1  31.9           4           89   71       1925           14   1980   Europe.
2  17.0           8          302  140       3449           11   1971       US.
3  15.0           8          400  150       3761           10   1971       US.
4  30.5           4           98   63       2051           17   1978       US.
```

```
x = x.values
print(x)
```

```
[[14.0 8 '350' ... '4209' 12 1972]
 [31.9 4 '89' ... '1925' 14 1980]
 [17.0 8 '302' ... '3449' 11 1971]
 ...
 [22.0 6 '232' ... '2835' 15 1983]
 [18.0 6 '232' ... '3288' 16 1972]
 [22.0 6 '250' ... '3353' 15 1977]]
```

When I run the fit() function, I get the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

So, I'm guessing that is because of the values I got in quotes.
Is there anyway around this, and if you understand why I'm getting some values in quotes please let me know.
(cars.csv is a normal csv file with nothing special so idk)

Comment: try `x = x.apply(pd.to_numeric)` before `x=x.values`. But `y` is an object column...

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the columns stored as strings in CSV file to float like this:

```
df['columnname'].apply(lambda x:float(x))
```